# Replacing div height with it's width (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using a script that automatically creates the width of my div's to make them fit across the width of the page. I would like to have the height match that.

I'm hoping for a jquery solution that will read the width and make that the height as well.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a single div:

```
$("#mydiv").css("height", $("#mydiv").css("width"));
```

For multiple divs:

```
$("div").each(function() {
    $(this).css("height", $(this).css("width"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [css](http://api.jquery.com/css):

```
​$("my_selector").css("height", function() { 
    return $(this).width();
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/REsfs/